# MongoDb. ReplaceOne and SetOnInsert

Tags: c#, mongodb

Is it possible to combine usages of `ReplaceOne` method and `SetOnInsert` as it is used with method `Update`? I would like to replace one document in collection with another one and set some fields if the document is inserting. I can do it with `Update` method but in this case I have to set each field manually

Comment: Which driver do you use?

Comment: According to Mongo documentation "ReplaceOne" doesn't possess the update operators, including `$setOnInsert`. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/method/db.collection.replaceOne/
The alternative I've used is deleting then inserting in bulk operations, but this make the _id instable. Updating is also possible but it will keep stale fields around. A "replace" option in the "update" operation would be more relevant...

Answer (score 0):

[For MondoDriver](http://%20https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/)

```
collection.FindOneAndUpdateAsync(
                Builders<TopicViewModel>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, @event.AggregateRootId),
                Builders<TopicViewModel>.Update.Set(x => x.Attachments, model.Attachments).Set(y=>y.Name,"New Value"));
```

Comment: If I understand you set each field manually, but I need to do it automatically